# menubar in css gets shorter in width in IE shows fine in ff and chrome

Tags: html, css

menu bar is made in css it works fine in ff and chrome but shorter in width in IE.I used a div with id container and then nav ul and li in another container with id menu. The css is written for id menu.

Comment: It would be better if you show us the html and css used.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please read this article and try to improve your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS reset. This makes sure that the size and spacing is always the same independent the browser.
See more: [About CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)